# My Windows 7 Lenovo laptop won't detect my iPhone 4S but it will charge it?

Tags: iphone, windows, charging

For the last 5 months my iPhone 4S won't connect to my Windows 7 Lenovo laptop or iTunes. It will charge in 2 of my USB ports, and I've tried 3 different cables.

I've tried following tips off Apple support and also from Google but still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Normally that would be a question for our friends at Microsoft, but lets try to help you here.

Charging using USB is a dumb function!, so do not pay to much attention to that.

The question is,

Do you have the right driver in your Win7 for the ihone?

How to do that can be [read here](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1538):

iOS: Device not recognized in iTunes for Windows

Symptoms

Your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch may not appear under Devices in iTunes after you connect it to your Windows PC.